# org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 in C#

Tags: java, c#, base64, converters

I want to convert a Java class into a C# class.
The Java class includes `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` and uses lots of its methods.

Is there any similar class available in C# that has the same methods and/or same functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These may help?

[Convert.FromBase64String Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Convert.ToBase64String Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

For URL safety I would look into the [JWT spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-signature-08#appendix-C). It shows the following code:

```
 static string base64urlencode(byte [] arg)
 {
   string s = Convert.ToBase64String(arg); // Regular base64 encoder
   s = s.Split('=')[0]; // Remove any trailing '='s
   s = s.Replace('+', '-'); // 62nd char of encoding
   s = s.Replace('/', '_'); // 63rd char of encoding
   return s;
 }

 static byte [] base64urldecode(string arg)
 {
   string s = arg;
   s = s.Replace('-', '+'); // 62nd char of encoding
   s = s.Replace('_', '/'); // 63rd char of encoding
   switch (s.Length % 4) // Pad with trailing '='s
   {
     case 0: break; // No pad chars in this case
     case 2: s += "=="; break; // Two pad chars
     case 3: s += "="; break; // One pad char
     default: throw new System.Exception(
       "Illegal base64url string!");
   }
   return Convert.FromBase64String(s); // Standard base64 decoder
 }
```

Comment: I have edited my answer to include URL safety. What do you need more?